# What are my options for Private Video Hosting?

Tags: video, youtube, video-hosting

I have a client that basically wants YouTube between a login screen. I know that YouTube offers private video hosting but this service is restricted to 25 users.

**Question:** *I am in the need of 'Private' video hosting ideal for a few hundred
 users, Does anyone know a good YouTube Alternative which will meet the requirements of my client.*

Answer (score 6):

I have been talking to vzaar ([vzaar.com](http://vzaar.com/)) about a similar project.  They are cheaper than Brightcove and have an decent API which is available on all pricing plans (unlike Brightcove who only give you access to the API on an expensive plan).  They use the Edgecast CDN.  Note - haven't actually committed or used them in anger yet, but on paper they seem ok.

Comment: You can also password protect individual videos with vzaar, which might be another way of doing private videos: http://vzaar.com/features/password_protection. I've worked with vzaar and they are an excellent video hosting service, and run by very friendly people (if you ever need to get in contact with them.)

Answer (score 5):

[Vimeo Plus](http://vimeo.com/plus) is $9.95/month or $59.95/year, and offers domain level privacy:

> Choose exactly where your videos can be embedded on the web. There are no limits to the number of websites you can choose and you'll always have complete control of your video outside of Vimeo. You even have the option to completely hide your video on Vimeo.com so it will only show up on the sites you want it to, and nowhere else.

Comment: As AndyBeard pointed out, Vimeo is not for commercial use. Including Plus. See http://vimeo.com/terms

Comment: Vimeo Pro ($200) is for businesses - http://vimeo.com/pro

Answer (score 3):

YouTube also offers "unlisted" videos which allow you to put a video on YouTube but not have it show up on your user page or in searches - you just require the URL in order to find it.

[More Details at the YouTube help page](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181547)

Comment: Ya that's the current best plan b, but still doesn't work great as people can easily share it

Answer (score 1):

+1 http://www.brightcove.com/

I'm using their services for a client project right now, and I must say they rock.  Video analytics (see where people are dropping off in your videos, which are the most popular, etc) and you manage the videos on Brightcove's administrative backend.  Very easy to maintain, swap, etc.

I'm still new to their services though, but I'd definitely say check them out.  No Youtube, or Vimeo logos/branding on your videos or video player (which is essential for my client.)

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo is not for commercial use

Personally for a workable commercial solution I would use Amazon, MaxCDN or Akamai (through VPS.net)

All 3 have the ability now to lock content to a domain. Amazon you can programatically expire the links and there are plenty of existing solutions to do that in PHP, or as say a full WordPress plugin.

You would need a way to handle encoding - either desktop such as format factory, or online encoder.com or zencoder.com are good options.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you have every played a video with the [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/). It's integrated in the [Bits on the Run](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run/) Video plattform. I use it for years and it's very developer and end user friendly (Different players, sizes, branding possible etc.) There's a well documented easy to use API for developers for consuming videos, stats, doing uploads. You cann add foreign viewers and/or hearing impared, DNS masks to serve feeds, players, thumbs and videos under your own domain. You have security options like "If you secure your videos they can only be accessed with signed URLs. This effectively prevents leeching".